# is it possible to use ConstructorParameters recursive?

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, prototype

I have class a and class b;

```
class a {
    constructor(params: {
        a: string;
    }) {

    }
}

class b {
    constructor(params: {
        b: string;
        bA: a;
    }) {

    }
}
```

ConstructorParameters:

```
type t = ConstructorParameters<typeof b>[0];
//type t = {
//    b: string;
//    bA: a;
//}
```

I want to do:

```
type t = ConstructorParametersRecursive<typeof b>;
// type t = {
//     b: string;
//     bA: {
//         a: string;
//     };
// }
```

All my class constructors have either one parameter or zero parameter.

Comment: What do you want to do with a zero-arg constructor (e.g., if you make `A` a zero-arg constructor, what should `ConstructorParametersRecursive<typeof b>` be)?  Note that there is no programmatic way to get from the type of an instance of a class to the constructor of the class (see [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841)) so if this is going to work at all you will need to manually annotate each class with the type of its constructor.  I will write that up as an answer if you're still interested.

Comment: if  ```A``` have zero-arg constructor, then ```ConstructorParametersRecursive<typeof b>``` must be ```{}```. I try to make ```ConstructorParametersRecursive<typeof b>``` beacause i don't want to track each ```ClassConstructorParam``` type. I want to do it automatically like ```ConstructorParameters```